# BEGIN IMMEDIATE could unexpectedly not be stepped after 0: 8/attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data, mpmediaitem

While using a `UITableView` to display `MPMediaItems` my log gets spammed with the following message:

```
BEGIN IMMEDIATE could unexpectedly not be stepped after 0: 8/attempt to write a readonly database
```

But I haven't any idea what this means. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Also having this problem

Comment: Fixed by updating/re-installing xCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably means you are using iTunes Match, and there is probably nothing you can do about these log messages.

EDIT: Further logging on my machine suggests that this message is generated by some collections when you call `representativeItem`. So if you're calling that method, perhaps you can avoid these log messages by avoiding that call (e.g. call `items[0]` instead).

The conclusion remains, though, that you are probably not doing anything wrong.

Comment: OK, see my further edit. My testing on my own app shows that this console message is due to calling `representativeItem` on a collection.

Comment: That may be the problem, but since this isn't a real issue, I'll stay using `representativeItem` which looks cleaner to me.

Comment: Well, I agree to some extent, but one must ask oneself, what does `representativeItem` do? It chooses an item. But that's something you can do just as well. So if `representativeItem` is going to barf these messages, making your app look bad, it seems to me that there's no harm in just specifying an item yourself. - I have submitted a bug report to Apple, and I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Maybe not iTunes Match, but maybe using iCloud for sharing your music across your devices?